# Foreign language support for HTML to PDF conversion by weasyprint

Tags: python, django, weasyprint, django-weasyprint

I Have an HTML code in which some texts are in the Hindi language. When I am converting the HTML file to PDF using weasyprint library, The generated PDF looks something like this:

[image]

This is my code for conversion:

```
from weasyprint import HTML
output = open('kt.html', 'rb')#, encoding='utf-8')
html = HTML(output)
html.write_pdf(target='ouput.pdf')
```

Tried using encoding also, but got this error:

> TypeError: Cannot set an encoding with a unicode input, set ['override_encoding', 'transport_encoding']

How to solve this issue?

**EDIT:**
HTML code looks something like this:
[image]

and HTML browser preview looks something like this

[image]

Comment: Isn’t it just that your font does not support those characters? I see there is a deleted answer with `font-family: sans-serif`, but have you tried Arial instead? Also, what does it look like when you open the source HTML with a browser? I suggest you put your HTML & CSS in the question, so we have a [mre].

Comment: Hi @DidierL, updated the question as per your requirement, Also, Arial is also not working. I think while conversion from HTML to pdf, weasyprint library is not able to recognize this HINDI font.

Comment: Please don’t put screenshots of code in your questions, it does not allow people to reproduce the problem. Put the real code instead. Also make your example minimal AND complete: reduce it to the bare minimum HTML/CSS that still reproduces the problem.

Comment: FYI, on my side I tried with the string “नमस्ते दुनिया”, and it worked with the default font, as long as I pass `-e utf8` on the command-line or `<meta charset="utf-8">` in the document. If I don’t, however, the result is completely different from yours: I get “`à¤¨à¤®à¤¸à¥à¤¤à¥‡ à¤¦à¥à¤¨à¤¿à¤¯à¤¾`”. I would still think the problem is your font and not an encoding issue.